# Rails 4 custom validate_uniqueness message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Is it possible that in the error message of `validate_uniqueness_of` to show the `id` of the record that already has the field that i'm checking the uniqueness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
validate :uniqueness_of_name

def uniqueness_of_name
   existing_record = Model.find_by_name(name)
   unless existing_record.nil?
     errors.add(:name, "Record #{existing_record.id} already has the name #{name}")
   end
end
```

Comment: Yowza... ! Beat me by 13 seconds. However note that this approach works if you are not using the myriad options provided by the default uniqueness validator.

Comment: This custom validation may not work correctly while updating the record.

Answer (score 6):

@vimsha's solution may work but I found a way neater way that allows to still use `validates_uniqueness_of` rather than creating your own validator:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :identifier, message: lambda{|x, y| "#{MyModel.find_by_identifier(y[:value]).id} is already taken" }
```

Comment: This works great. Out of curiosity, how were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

@usha's uniqueness validation code will incorrectly fail when updating an existing record since `Model.find_by_name(name)` returns the record being updated.

```
validate :uniqueness_of_name

def uniqueness_of_name(current_record)
    existing_record = Model.find_by_name(name)
    unless existing_record.nil? || existing_record.id == current_record.id
        errors.add(:name, "Record #{existing_record.id} already has the name #{name}")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 5.0 and higher with the new syntax

```
validates :your_attribute, uniqueness: { message: ->(_object, data) do 
                                           other_object = Model.find_by(your_attribute: data[:value])
                                           "#{data[:value]} is already taken by #{other_object.name}"
                                         end }
```

For more details: [RoR documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message).

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought that you could solve this by writing a custom validator, like so:

```
class NameValidator
  def validate record
    unless record.name.include? 'somestring'
      record.errors[:name] << "#{record.name} is not valid"
    end
  end
end
```

However, I don't think it is possible to access the `record`, as I have done in the example above.

`validate_uniqueness_of` doesn't give you access to the individual record until quite far down in the stack. Eventually the code gets through to [`validate_each`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/905b7df1fac8332547b9eb7fc4d5b083c6fc1031/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L15), at which point you have access to the individual record. Therefore, you would need to [implement your own `validate_each`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2e62af310d98fba78f338d916f7c17996446bc40/activemodel/lib/active_model/validator.rb#L66-73) or [extend the existing one](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/905b7df1fac8332547b9eb7fc4d5b083c6fc1031/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L15).

It doesn't look like there is a way to do it in Rails by default. Of course, I would be interested to know if there is a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what OP was after, but I wanted to add this here for those just looking to include the value of the attribute in the custom validation error message.

Use `%{value}` in your custom message.

Something like this:

```rb
validates :name, uniqueness: { message: "%{value} has already been taken." }
```

This will result in a message like "Joe has already been taken."

As per the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message):

> Message with dynamic attribute value. %{value} will be replaced
> with the actual value of the attribute. %{attribute} and %{model}
> are also available.

As can be seen in the documentation, `%{attribute}` and `%{model}` are also available.

To get a different attribute or do something more complex, you'll have to look at one of the other answers.